# Angular: disable form control properly so that I can read value later

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So here is my angular reactive form

```
  zoneEntryForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl(''),
    zonename: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

I am getting output by this code:

```
  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.zoneEntryForm.value);
  }
```

output

[image]

**[Note: code is a number, zone is a string]**

Now I want to read value from code and zone , but I need to set code field disable and still I want to read value from code field. (code is coming from db, I will have to make some get code function to set it, user won't input it. Later I need to send this code and zone name to somewhere else

both field should be blank by default

So here is my attempt

**attempt 1:**

```
  zoneEntryForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
    zonename: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

**output:**
[image]

see, now code field is no longer read by `onSubmit`

**Attempt : 2**

```
  zoneEntryForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl({disabled: true}),
    zonename: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

**output :**

[image]

Now my default blank value "" is gone

So How can I make code disabled and read from it properly at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get disabled `FormControl` value too, then you need to call `getRawValue()` method on `FormGroup`

> `this.zoneEntryForm.getRawValue()`

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fl4hie?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**TS Code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  zoneEntryForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl({
      value: '1234',
      disabled: true
    }),
    zonename: new FormControl('testzone'),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.zoneEntryForm.getRawValue());
    console.log(this.zoneEntryForm.getRawValue().code);
    console.log(this.zoneEntryForm.getRawValue().zonename);
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I just get value of code only or zone only after that?

Comment: @Frost updated the answer, you can call properties on `getRawValue()` method ;)

Answer (score 0):

The way you assigned a default value to code similarly you can assign the predefined value for code and read it as well on submit. If that value depends on some action you can declare a public variable and then asiign the same to it.

```js
this.codeValue = 'testCode'; //or assign anywhere as per condition 
zoneEntryForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl({value: this.codeValue, disabled: true}),
    zonename: new FormControl(''),
  });
```